# Upgrading from kernel 5.4.0-77 to compiled 5.13.0 fails to compile existing kernel modules

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, kernel-modules

I manually compiled the 5.13.0 kernel, and that went without a hitch. When installing the kernel, my drivers for my wifi card kept failing to compile, with this log:

```
DKMS make.log for rtl88x2bu-5.6.1 for kernel 5.13.0 (x86_64)
Mon 12 Jul 2021 12:09:24 PM EDT
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.13.0/build M=/var/lib/dkms/rtl88x2bu/5.6.1/build  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.13.0'

  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.
         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.
         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.

make[1]: *** [Makefile:731: include/config/auto.conf] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.13.0'
make: *** [Makefile:2284: modules] Error 2
```

I ran `make oldconfig && make prepare`, but the same thing happens.

System info: https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=10a0317592